# Symfony2 - redirecting to login page after register

Tags: symfony

i have problem with fosuserbundle. I created a custom register form and action but it works only when I'm logged in

```
/**
 * @Route("/account/register", name="register_account")
 */
public function registerAction(Request $request) {

    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    /*$pwd = $user->getPassword();
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.password_encoder');
    $pwd = $encoder->encodePassword($user, $pwd);
    $user->setPassword($pwd);*/

    if ($form->isValid()) {


    $user->addRole(User::ROLE_USER);
    $user->setEnabled(true);

        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Dodano!');
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('register_account');
    }
    return $this->render('default/register.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView() ]);
}
```

and when I'm not logged in it redirects me to login page i simply don't know where i made mistake

Answer (score 0):

You have made a little mistake: When your form is submitted and validated, you redirect to the same route of your initial action `register_account`.

Try something like that:

```
/.../

return $this->redirectToRoute('succes_page');

/.../
```

Where `succes_page` matches another action of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `/account/register` url is under `security firewall`.

You should make this url accessible without being logged in.

On your `security.yml` file add following lines:

```
security:
...
    firewalls:
    ...
        login_firewall:
            pattern:   ^/register/account
            anonymous: ~
        ...        
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/register/account, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Also you should change the redirect route to something else not the same registration route again. It's an infinite loop.

This route name should be something else lie success page or home page.

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('register_account');
```

You can always get more information about Symfony's security component [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html).

Comment: still nothing, it makes differences when controller with this action is in AppBundle when i rest (user entity) is in UserBundle?

Comment: Did you put the line under `access_control` to first line? Because symfony stops at first match.[more](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html)